# Why all of my .Net project's references are gone?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have created a web application project. While developing my application, I have installed some packages from NuGet and yet they still there in my project. But when I copy my project to another computer and try to run the project, there are many errors occurred because all references are marked with yellow alerts.

I open the project with file .sln
[image: This is the project root folder]

When I run the project, it generated a lot of error because it cannot find the libraries.
[image]

As Abhay Saraf's request, I provide the link to download .csproj section: http://www.hellomeo.net/Umbraco/EmployeeLeaveManagement.zip

Comment: Can you please post the .csproj section where these package references are listed?

Comment: I have add the link to download .csproj section.

Comment: Did you enable nuget to download missing references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check the packages.config file in your project to confirm all packages are listed in this file. Then please check your Visual Studio settings (Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> General), the options under Package Restore are all checked as below screenshot.
[image]

If above options are checked but the packages still not restore automatically, please use following ways to restore packages for entire solution.

1. Open Package Manager Console window from View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console.
2. Type command “Update-Package -reinstall”  to reinstall all packages in your current solution which will based on the packages that listed in the packages.config file.

Comment: Note: To force visual studio re-install packages, the packages must be removed before build.

Comment: In the packages.config file in myproject , all packages are NOT listed. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on one of the missing references, choose `Properties` and see what the Path is set to.  Is the Path correct?

Comment: Event if the path is set correct on my computer, but how can I assure it work find on other computer?

Answer (score 0):

Run `dnu restore` from the Package Manager Console

[image]